# Decimal to Hexadecimal recursively python

Tags: python, recursion

I can get the function to work regularly but when I do it recursively, it repeats infintely and I have to 'Ctrl C'to end it in the shell.

Non recursive

```
def convert_10_to_16(n):
  hexlist =[]
  x = n // 16
  if x < 10:
    hexlist.append(x)
  elif (x == 10):
    hexlist.append('A')
  elif (x == 11):
    hexlist.append('B')
  elif (x == 12):
    hexlist.append('C')
  elif (x == 13):
    hexlist.append('D')
  elif (x == 14):
    hexlist.append('E')
  elif (x == 15):
    hexlist.append('F')

  y = n % 16
  if y < 10:
    hexlist.append(y)
  elif (y == 10):
    hexlist.append('A')
  elif (y == 11):
    hexlist.append('B')
  elif (y == 12):
    hexlist.append('C')
  elif (y == 13):
    hexlist.append('D')
  elif (y == 14):
    hexlist.append('E')
  elif (y == 15):
    hexlist.append('F')
  return ''.join(hexlist)
```

Recursive

```
def convert_10_to_16(n):
  hexlist =[]
  x = n // 16
  if x < 10:
    hexlist.append(x)
  elif (x == 10):
    hexlist.append('A')
  elif (x == 11):
    hexlist.append('B')
  elif (x == 12):
    hexlist.append('C')
  elif (x == 13):
    hexlist.append('D')
  elif (x == 14):
    hexlist.append('E')
  elif (x == 15):
    hexlist.append('F')

  y = n % 16
  if y < 10:
    hexlist.append(y)
  elif y >= 10:
    z = y 
    convert_10_to_16(z)
```

I'm not sure how I can get it to work recursively so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: the indentation is off

Comment: yeah its correct in my python shell. didnt copy over correctly i guess

Comment: You know you can do `assert 'A' == hex(10).upper()[-1]`, right? `hex` is a built-in function with [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex).

Comment: we cant use built in python functions :/

Comment: Why can't you use built in functions? Your manager is insane. I would complain to human resources.

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive case and a base case.

But more important than that is to use variable names that **have meaning**.

```
def convert_digit_to_hex(x):
    if x < 10:
        return str(x)
    elif (x == 10):
        return 'A'
    elif (x == 11):
        return 'B'
    elif (x == 12):
        return 'C'
    elif (x == 13):
        return 'D'
    elif (x == 14):
        return 'E'
    elif (x == 15):
        return 'F'

def convert_number_to_hex(n):
    remaining_digits = n // 16
    last_digit       = n % 16

    if remaining_digits == 0:
        return convert_digit_to_hex(last_digit)
    else:
        return convert_number_to_hex(remaining_digits) + convert_digit_to_hex(last_digit)
```

Comment: meaning, like "first_digit" which is the last digit? ;) and you switched the two, so you have a bug.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: That I did.

Comment: Neither `n` nor `x` have meaning for me.  And `str()` is a built-in function, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply, and recursively, without built-in functions and without a `list` data structure:

```
DIGITS = "0123456789ABCDEF"

def convert_10_to_16(number):
    number, remainder = number // 16, DIGITS[number % 16]

    if number:
        return convert_10_to_16(number) + remainder

    return remainder

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for number in range(257):
        print(number, '=', convert_10_to_16(number))
```

Answer (score -1):

When doing a recursive function for converting decimal to hexadecimal in python, you can use the "%" which is a string formatting operator. By using "%x" or "%X" it helps convert the decimal into hexadecimal.

```
def main():
    #Asks user for decimal
    number = int(input("Enter a decimal: "))
    num = convert(number)
    print(num)

def convert(dec):
    #Converts the decimal to hexadecimal
    hex = "%X" % dec
    print("The hexadecimal is: ", end="")
    #Prints hexadecimal
    return hex

main()
```

Comment: Ehm...that's not recursive at all!

Comment: Even if this is not recursive, the function "%X" or "%x" will still change the decimal to hexadecimal.

Comment: Of course, but if somebody asks for a recursive solution the solution should be recursive!